# How to detect whether file is uploaded by the user or not in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a post system, where, if the user writes only text and doesn't upload an image, an error image should not appear (only plain text should appear after submitting).

So I have to check whether an image is uploaded or not.

The below code does the work of posting only Text.

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if (($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'])==1){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class='postuser'>";

    echo "<div id='img_div1' class='caption'>";
    echo "<p>".$row['image_text1']."</p>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image1']."' width='288px'>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    }

    else
    {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class='postuser'>";

    echo "<div id='img_div1' class='caption'>";
    echo "<p>".$row['image_text1']."</p>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

**PS:** I have used file_exists() function and is_uploaded_file() function with both $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'] and $_FILES['image1']['name'], tried many other ways, but to no help.

Hope nobody closes the question this time, please.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php appropriately enough.

Comment: Funk Forty Niner, I tried this with the code just now. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class='postuser'>";
    echo "<div id='img_div1' class='caption'>";
    echo "<p>".$row['image_text1']."</p>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image1']."' width='288px'>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
} else
    {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class='postuser'>";

    echo "<div id='img_div1' class='caption'>";
    echo "<p>".$row['image_text1']."</p>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: tried it, didn't work.... :(

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The uploaded images are not getting displayed. Only the text appears. I want to display "image + text" if Image is uploaded by user, else only "text".

Comment: Tried using      'if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $target))'     .........but same problem.